# Shapeless narrow type loss

Tags: scala, shapeless, singleton-type

In the following example

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

val concat = "right".narrow

def extract[s <: String](x: s)(implicit witness: Witness.Aux[s]): String = witness.value

extract(concat)
```

I'm getting an error

> Error: could not find implicit value for parameter `witness:shapeless.Witness.Aux[String("right")]`

The thing I'm trying to do is a type level DSL which is heavily relied on singleton types.

Since singleton typed literals are badly supported outside typelevel's fork, I was hoping to develop value-based DSL in addition to type literals, and preservation of usable singleton types in value types is critical for this task.
So I'm looking for any workaround which allows me to extract singleton string witness from value's type later.

#### Edit

operations using `.witness` instead of `.narrow` are working perfectly, but I'm still looking for solution for pure types without `Witness` wrapping

Comment: Did you try create an extractor??

Comment: @PavelOliynyk can you explain what kind of extractor do you mean? The `unapply` one?

Comment: This one: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html I've got the feeling you will need to implement unapply,

Comment: @PavelOliynyk can you write an example how the `unapply` extractor could help with type loss problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a failure of type inference ... you'll find that,

```
extract[concat.type](concat)
```

will work as you expect.

That's not particularly helpful, as I imagine you want to infer the singleton type from the value argument to `extract`. shapeless provides an implicit conversion to `Witness` types, so the following might work in your context,

```
def extract(witness: Witness.Lt[String]): String = witness.value
```

This will accept both literal `Strings` and narrowed values.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed